# Android Studio: MapView app crashing when loading

Tags: android, maps

Im trying to display a map with my location marker on it. Since this error is happening I've decided to create a simple basic application from Android Studio templates following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdCRxEn540U). Ive did almost everything like the tutorial asks. Generated API key correctly on Google site. Same error is happening on my main application: app crashes when loading the map view (log cat does not show line error). The differences may be on the tools like SDKs and API. So im showing you guys here to see if someone got any clue about it.

This is [SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUYdP.png) print

And this is the [APIs in use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zsCT.png)

Again, I didn't change anything on the code of the MapView template app from Android Studio.

What may be happening?

Log cat msgs:

```
08-30 19:49:42.694 17966-18008/com.appdidier.testmaps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
    Process: com.appdidier.testmaps, PID: 17966
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at el.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):3)
        at ek.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):4)
        at em.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):51)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):11)
        at dw.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):16)
        at dw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):61)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/app_chimera/m/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):25)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at el.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):3) 
        at ek.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):4) 
        at em.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):51) 
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):11) 
        at dw.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):16) 
        at dw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):61)
```

Comment: Logcat does not show any errors at all?

Comment: @nasch just updated with the error shown

Comment: I would search for that error and see if any results help you: https://www.google.com/search?q=Didn%27t+find+class+org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion

Comment: @nasch i didn't know about that error. Apprently adding this to manifest solved the issue: <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and after adding this line to the Manifest file it worked again

```
<application
   ....
   <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779) in Google about this error

Comment: I had the same error and  the above solution solved it. Thank you!